# C# Keyboard Shortcuts quit working after calling 2nd XAML window

Tags: c#, xaml, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a software that uses multiple XAML windows for different instances: for example, to export some information, I've created secondary XAML windows with different format than the mother software. They work fine.

My problem is that, if I use my software without calling any of these secondary XAML windows, the shortcuts work pretty well. But as soon as I call this new XAML windows, the shortcuts don't work anymore. I need to restart the program so that they comeback alive.

Any clue on this behaviour?
In addition, I was not able yet to create shortcuts like CTRL+Letter for example. I have seen plenty of codes, it seems pretty straight-forward but they just don't work...

Code

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Key key = e.Key;


    if ((key == Key.Left) && previousButton.IsEnabled)
        button_PreviewMouseDown(previousButton, null);
    else if ((key == Key.Right) && nextButton.IsEnabled)
        button_PreviewMouseDown(nextButton, null);
    //New Label
    else if (key == Key.L)
        //else if (key == Key.LeftAlt && e.Key.ToString() == "L")
        NewLabel_Click(sender, e);
    // Begin Event
    else if (key == Key.B)
        BeginEvent_Click(sender, e);
    // End Event
    else if (key == Key.E)
        EndEvent_Click(sender, e);
    // Delete Label
    else if (key == Key.K)
        DeleteLabel_Click(sender, e);
    else if (key == Key.R)
        // Delete Event
        DeleteEvent_Click(sender, e);
    // Edit Label
    else if (key == Key.I)
        EditLabel_Click(sender, e);
    // Edit Event
    else if (key == Key.F)
        EditEvent_Click(sender, e);
}
```

EDIT 1

I found out now that as soon as I call a C# popup message box just saying "Event Created OK" the shortcuts comeback alive again!

```
MessageBox.Show("Event Created");
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: care to share your code and the exact problem

Comment: Should use a switch statement, especially for readability; I voted up, good luck.

Comment: Idea to call event handler directly with some (probably wrong) `sender` and `e` is bad, rather move code from handler into separate method and then you can call that method from different event handlers. It's not clear what happens when you show second window (add related code). And description of the problem *"don't work"* is awesome. What doesn't work? Does event handler not called anymore (set breakpoint at first line of it and see yourself)? Could it be what some other control get focus (or window is not active anymore, thus no input)?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use **RoutedCommands**.
With a RoutedCommand you assign **KeyGestures**.

example

```
/// <summary>
/// Save Log command
/// </summary>
public static readonly RoutedCommand SaveLog =
    new RoutedCommand("SaveLog", typeof(Commands),
        new InputGestureCollection 
        {
            new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control,"Save log contents to a file. (Ctl+S)")
        });
```

Assign the RoutedCommand in your xaml

```
            <Button Style="{StaticResource LoggingWindowSaveLogButton}" Command ="{x:Static local:Commands.SaveLog}" />
```

Bind the command to your window

```
    <!-- Command Bindings-->
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Commands.SaveLog}" Executed="SaveLogCommand" CanExecute="SaveLogCommandCanExecute"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Then implement **SaveLogCommandCanExecute** and **SaveLogCommand**

if SaveLogCommandCanExecute  returns **false** it will automatically disable any GUI that the RoutedCommand is bound to.

Keep in mind the window that has the keybinding **MUST** have focus.