# Adding a list of key bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my WPF MVVM application each model-view contains a list of buttons.  Which are valid for that user control.

```
private List<myButton> _buttons;
```

I am displaying them like this:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding buttons}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                    
                    <Button   Width="100" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,5,5,5" Command="{Binding command}"  Content="{Binding name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Which works just fine.

Now what i would like to do is have key bindings on some of my buttons Save for example  cntr + s.

How do I add key bindings for some of the buttons.   From what i have found so far you would do something like this

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Z" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand1}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="H" Modifiers="Alt" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand2}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

I tried adding it as a list but that didnt work at all.  There must be a way of bulding the key bindings for the some of my buttons.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361350/keyboard-shortcuts-in-wpf

Comment: Sounds like you are thinking about [binding InputBindings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9385129/1997232).

Comment: @bwegs I tried that one already it doesn't work because buttons is a list. I need to be able to loop somehow creating the different key bindings.

Comment: @DaImTo same problem here... still no one has answer to help ! can you also double-check my thread? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423870/c-sharp-keyboard-shortcuts-quit-working-after-calling-2nd-xaml-window

Comment: I also use WPF with XAML windows... and they just stop working. But I am able to make the bindings

Comment: @16per9 not a bad idea but that will require that I add that to all of the user controls I am trying to keep code out of the code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

The thing is that Inputbindings are a window thing not a user control thing.  Yes I am new at WPF.

By adding the following to the Mainwindow.xml it will fire savecommand on which ever usercontrol is currently selected.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding  Key="s" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxMenu, Path=SelectedItem.SaveCommand }" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

If the usercontrol / modelview what ever its called doesn't have a savecommand it just does nothing.

Comment: Yes it sure does and whats even better i dont get an error if the usercontrol doesnt have a SaveCommand method

Comment: OK great! Thanks! - I'll try to replicate this on my software :p